Positive measures and determination of a complex measure
The following was an assignment problem which I'm stuck on

Let $\lambda(E)=\int_{E}\text{sin}xdx$, for any Lebesgue measurable subset of $[0,\pi]$. Show that $\lambda$ is a positive measure on $[0,\pi]$. Is it absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure? Justify your answer. Can you find a complex measure on $[0,\pi]$ whose total variation is $\lambda$?

What I've done so far is this:

By properties of Lebesgue integration, $\lambda(\phi)=0$. Let $A=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}$ where $\{A_{k}\}$ is a disjoint sequence of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $[0,\pi]$. Then, $\lambda(A)=\int_{A}\sin{x}dx=\int_{[0,\pi]}\sin{x}\cdot\chi_{A}dx=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\int_{[0,\pi]}\sin{x}\cdot\chi_{A_{k}}dx=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\int_{A_{k}}\sin{x}dx=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda(A_{k})$, where the third equality follows from MCT. Thus, $\lambda$ is a positive measure. Moreover if $m(E)=0$, then $\int_{E}\sin{x}dx=0$, so $\lambda<<m$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

So my questions are: Is the proof so far okay? How do I determine the complex measure whose total variation is $\lambda$? I know it has to do with Radon-Nikodym theorem, but can't really proceed.
